# PHP/mySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - did INSERT or UPDATE occur?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL query using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that I am runnining from a PHP script. I would like to test whether an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` occurred. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

"With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated."

You can use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to determine the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 2):

I had to figure this out one time, so I'm referring to my notes on the matter.

The following query:

```
INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...,  id = LAST_INSERT_ID(  id)
```

Where 'id' is the primary key on the table, allows you to call [mysqli_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_affected_rows), which will return:

1. 0 - Row existed, nothing updated
2. 1 - No row existed, inserted
3. 2 - Row existed, something updated

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know... even though I'm using mysql not mysqli, so I'm not sure whether return 0 is valid with mysql_affected_rows()